# How to mount an extra partition in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I have a desktop computer with two hard-drives. One drive has Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it (64-bit, UEFI).  The other drive has been partitioned into approximately two equal partitions.  One of these has Windows 8.1 installed on it and the other partition (~ 450 GB) is unallocated space.  I would like to use this unallocated space as an extra partition of my Ubuntu system,to be used mainly for backups.  Could someone please give me detailed instructions on how to do this (mount point, etc.)?  I have very little expertise.  I have Gparted installed, if this is what I should be using.

Comment: Are both drives gpt partitioned? You may want some shared data in an NTFS partition, but for Linux backups you need an ext4 formatted partition. If unallocated is not inside the NTFS partition, just use gparted to create a new ext4 partition. You probably want to permanently mount it with fstab. And will have to give yourself ownership & permissions. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: @oldfred is it must to have ext4 ? Why can't we use NTFS ? An answer below suggests to use NTFS

Comment: If just data, NTFS is ok. But if any Linux system files you need to use ext4 or another Linux format or use a compressed image inside the NTFS partition. NTFS does not support Linux owership & permissions which for data you can easily reset. But throughout system are various settings that are just about impossible to reset.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I figured out. I will suggest you to re-format that unallocated space in ntfs format ( since this is easy on windows) and mount it on your ubuntu on any appropriate directory.

follow as below:

1. you need to get the list for active HDDs

> fdisk -l

you should have all your disks listed as below corresponding to the partition.

Device Boot

/dev/sdb1

/dev/sdb2

/dev/sdb3

2. create a mount point anywhere you want i.e.

> mkdir /mnt/share

and directory permission to 0777.

3. Mount the file system by using the following command

> mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sdb3 /mnt/share

4. Now cd to the directory and you should be able to "ls" the items.

You can also mount the disk permanently by editing the /etc/fstab file. Hope this helps.

Good Luck!